# Kendo Grid Drag and Drop With Cell Editing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having issue with kendo drag and drop cell editing.

Change the value in first column and click any above row, the value is lost.

Regards

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/UsCFK/

Comment: I think you need to give some more description here.. I don't see any issue there..

Comment: @Jayantha, it is quite easy to produce, change the value in the id column and then click any other row, you will notice that id value is roll back to existing value.